# CMAKE - makefile target for a library

Tags: cmake

I'm currently changing the build system on my project, from gnu makefiles to cmake (that generate makefiles).

My project generates several libraries (.lib), and several executables (.exe).

Currently i generate the makefiles using the following command :

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

The generated makefiles contain an `all` target, as well as a target for every executable (compiled as such with the `add_executable` cmake directive), so i can compile a subset of the project (which saves a lot of time) : `make executable_1; make executable_2` and so on.

However, there is no target for the libraries (compiled as such with the `add_library` cmake directive) so i cannot do `make library_1` for example. I want to do this because it would save a lot of time.

I tried to add a dummy executable  in the library's cmake, and link the library to this executable (which only contains a main without actually using library_1's code).

```
add_library(library_1 test.cpp)
add_executable(dummy_exe dummy_main.cpp)
target_link_library(dummy_exe library_1)
```

It does add a target for dummy_exe but does not build the library because it does not actually need to link any of the library_1's code.

This was a workaround attempt anyway, and i'd rather just call `make library_1` after all. Is there any way to add a makefile target for a library using cmake ?

Comment: Using `add_library` should create a target in the Makefile, maybe you overlooked it? If you are sure it's not created, please create a minimal example and detail your environment (CMake version, OS).

Comment: `make help` will list all the known targets and for me does list the library targets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by w-m and Fred, CMAKE indeed create a target for libraries in the Makefile.

I was trying to build the library with the cmake subproject name of the library instead of the library name.

`make help` was indeed of big help to find this issue, as it lists everything that can be built.